# App configuration is unable to pick assembly up

Tags: c#, app-config

I've a project structure like that:

```
App
|__UI.exe
|__folder
   |__Assembly.dll
   |__Assembly.dll.config
```

The content of `Assembly.dll.config` is:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="backend" value="qa"/>
  </appSetings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="qa" type="Backend.Implementations.Lest.Settings.BackendSection,Assembly"/>
    <section name="dev" type="Backend.Implementations.Lest.Settings.BackendSection,Assembly"/>
  </configSections>
  <qa scope="qa">
    <endpoints>
      <endpoint host="localhost" port="1111" app="webapi"/>
      <endpoint host="localhost" port="2222" app="authz"/>
    </endpoints>
  </qa>
  <dev scope="development">
    <endpoints>
      <endpoint host="localhost" port="1111" app="webapi"/>
      <endpoint host="localhost" port="2222" app="authz"/>
    </endpoints>
  </dev>
</configuration>
```

When I'm trying to get the configuration from `Assembly` looking on the same folder it's located, I'm receiving an `ConfigurationErrorsException in System.Configuration.dll` telling me:

> it's impossible to load `Assembly` assembly. System is unable to find
>   the specified file.

This is the code I'm using for loading the configuration:

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(LESTBackend))).Location);
ConfigurationSection section = configuration.GetSection("qa"); << Here the exception is raised.
```

Any ideas? Where is Configuration looking for?

Comment: The configuration needs to be on the EXE. Most likely, it is looking for UI.exe.config which gets created from the app.config in the EXE project (same as the DLL). What type of project is the EXE?

Comment: @JeffSiver, it's the default behaviour. As you can see, I'm getting `.config` file from the location where `Assembly` assembly is: `OpenExeConfiguration((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(LESTBackend))).Location)`. So, the configuration file is loaded, the problem only is related with the Type loading. Remember that I've load the `config` file from the location where `Asembly` is, and tehn I figure out `.net` should have to be able to load whichever type in whichever assembly located at the same folder-level.